# probability measure in Benjamini Schramm graph limit theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, category-theory

I have read about the Benjamini Schramm graph limit theory and that it works for sparse graphs. For example, line graphs of length $n$ converge to an infinite line graph which extends to infinity in both directions. Or a tree with 2 sprouts, successively growing with $n$, converges to the canopy tree for $n\to\infty$.

However, I am not totally clear why probabiliy measures need to enter this limit theory, and why for example the limit graph corresponds to a probability measure? I feel I am overlooking something that is central to the whole theory.

I have a naive heuristic for myself, which is:

1. this limit theory requires root vertices in the graph to define distance.
2. And instead of staying with one root vertex, you let the roots be randomly distributed across the graph, so suddenly probability theory enters.

-- But this naive heuristic does not give me the full understanding why the limit graphs correspond to probability measures. And why most parts of this theory practically "take place" in spaces of probability measures.

One more question out of curiosity - in category theory terms, is there a functor from the "category of graphs" (or sparse graphs) to the "category of probabiliy measures", and is it related to the Benjamini Schramm limit? (This question is very "freestyle" and maybe I am confusing a lot of things here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Benjamini-Schramm limit (of a sequence of growing sparse graphs with a uniform root) is an infinite  random graph with a distinguished root, i.e., a probability measure on rooted graphs. In the case of the canopy tree, it is important to specify that the root is at distance $k$ from the boundary with probability $2^{-1-k}$. Another example is the giant component of  the Erdos-Renyi random graphs $G(n,\lambda/n)$ where $\lambda>1$. These giant components converge (in the Benjamini-Schramm sense) to the family tree of the Galton-Watson branching process with offspring distribution Poisson$(\lambda)$, conditioned to survive forever.

The paper [1] may be helpful.

[1] Benjamini, Itai, and Nicolas Curien. "Ergodic theory on stationary random graphs." Electronic Journal of Probability 17 (2012): 1-20.

Comment: thanks a lot for your really helpful answer and for the reference! I will take a look!

Comment: I am glad it is helpful. Do you know how to accept an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers